# perl: refactor s/.../.../g -> while {}?

Tags: regex, perl, map-function

I've got a monstrous eval-substitution; here's a simplified version

```
$ perl -wpe 's@(for )(\w+)@$1 . "user " . qx/id $2/@ge'
```

which replaces e.g.

```
Stats for root are bad
Stats for user uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
 are bad
```

Is there an idiom to turn the s/.../.../g into a loop? Something like

```
while (m@(for )(\w+)@) {
  # explicitly replace match with expression computed over several LOCs 
}
```

Or maybe somehow use map()?

Comment: `/g` is a loop. It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: One can indeed refactor a `s/.../.../g` expression to use while. But your sample input only requires one substitution (i.e., it doesn't require the `/g` flag). Are you looking to express the substitution differently? Or is your real question about refactoring the monstrous replacement pattern?

Comment: I thought it was the norm provide a simplified, workable example. The actual code involves successive substitutions inside the main s///e... And I stated what kind of refactored code I'm looking for

Comment: More along the lines while (m@...@) { replace substr corresponding to $& with computed expression } -- where computed is NOT a one-liner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idiom is to use `s///eg`. It undeniably better than the alternative you are seeking.

```perl
s{pat}{ repl }eg;
```

is equivalent to

```perl
my $out = '';
my $last_pos = 0;
while (m{pat}g) {
   $out .= substr($_, $last_pos, $-[0] - $last_pos) . do { repl };
   $last_pos = $+[0];
}

$_ = $out . substr($_, $last_pos);
```

---

Because you hinted that there would be more than one statements to be executed in the replacement expression, I'd write your code as follows:

```perl
s{for \K(\w+)}{
   ...
   ...
}eg;
```

The advantage of curlies is that they can be nested.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for -- though I was hoping for a more idiomatic version (but not as cumbersome as s///ge)

Comment: There's nothing cryptic about `{ statements }`, which is the part you are seeking to replace. In fact, you'll find that I use that not one but twice in the `while` version.

Comment: It's not the {} statements. I would have preferred not to use an explicit accumulator, and maybe use map

Comment: There's no explicit accumulator in your original code. Your original code has none of the problems you state you want to solve..

Comment: Re "Got it, didn't see the second part / edits", Just added that. The advantage of curlies is that they can be nested

Comment: I did ask about map() in the original -- it's even got the tags. But nevermind, this is the solution.

Comment: Solution using map: `map {; } s@(for )(\w+)@$1 . "user " . qx/id $2/@ge`